# Will search engines understand the HTML template tag with client side rendering?

Tags: seo, javascript, tags, template, render

I have a page that uses  HTML `<template>` tags. I don't know the page length like this.

```html
<template>Some Html</template>
<template>Some Html2</template>
<template>Some Html3</template>
...
...
...
<template>Some Html</template>
```

I render them via JS when they will be visible (using Intersection_Observer).

How does it affect on SEO? Do I need to output the same HTML in the noscript tag for SEO?

Comment: What types of SEO problems are you worried about?  Are you worried about Google (which will execute your JavaScript) or other search engines that won't?

Comment: I am worry because there isn't 100% guarantee that after changing server-side render to client-side, it will not  affect to SEO. If you google this question you will find out there is no 100% answer for this question and because I am't SEO specialist  I asking help from SEO specialists .

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/204310091/does-google-read-html-in-template-template-tag?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

> I render them via js when they will be visible

If you render server-side, this does not matter at all.

If you render client-side, it could affect SEO. Is the "some HTML" part actual HTML? Could a browser display the page without JavaScript-rendering?

Comment: Hey,

I am rendering in the client side.

"Could a browser display the page without JavaScript-rendering?" - it depends of question 2(I don't want to use noscript tag because the html size can be very large because I will duplicate the html 1 in template and 1 in noscript).


The goal of this is that , when you have a large dom, dom render is slow. that is why I am trying to render a part which is visible.

Comment: @Malte `<template>` tags are written by the server, but those are invisible on the client side until JavaScript transforms them, so I can see why there could be some concerns with SEO around them.

Comment: They are visible in the client side(template tags contains html with text,images and etc.). Let's say I have this normal html now

<div><h1> Lorem Ispum .... </h1></div>

now I am just wrapping it with template tag and rendering via js on the client-side when it will be visible(using Intersection_Observer). Does it affect on SEO?



<template><div><h1> Lorem Ispum .... </h1></div></template>